# SSRS Displaying tablix values on the column chart

Tags: sql, reporting-services, charts, highcharts, ssrs-2008

[image]I have a tablix that shows grouping of detail rows.
 [image]This is calculated based on the Days_R field.[image]I have enabled hide on detail rows.Expression is using the calculation to display 5 grouped rows based on the number of days in DAYS_R field.
  I have to show tablix values on the chart. It should display like 5 series. In category axis, I have copied the same expression in the tablix to the chart category axis. It displays like shown below.[image]Could anyone please help me how to plot the exact 5 series in SSRS column chart?

`Added part  of  sample data, it has more rows and more columns.I have to group by DAY_R field based on the expression in the comment and  show the count of PO_ID on Y axis.

Comment: Are you using the same expression as the tablix in Category groups?

Comment: yes!  I am using the same like this one               switch(Fields!DAYS_R.Value<=5,"0-5",
Fields!DAYS_R.Value>5 and Fields!DAYS_R.Value<=10,"06-10",
Fields!DAYS_R.Value>10 and Fields!DAYS_R.Value<=15,"11-15",
Fields!DAYS_R.Value>15 and Fields!DAYS_R.Value<=20,"16-20",
Fields!DAYS_R.Value>20 and Fields!DAYS_R.Value<=25,"21-25",
Fields!DAYS_R.Value>25 ,">25")

Comment: Where are you putting that expression?

Comment: share a sample of your dataset

Comment: DataSet has lot of fields. I am  hiding the details rows. I am showing details in different table. Summary is calculated in SSRS based on the condition (expression like above) shown in the tablix. Sample data is attached in the question at the top.  Is it possible that using array to get both x axis and y axis values and plot in the chart without using dataset?If yes could you please guide me on how to do that.

Comment: unfortunately that is not possible in SSRS. The data you provided in the question is being grouped but I want to see unaggregated data to try reproducing your issue.

Comment: would it be possible using range chart to plot the data in the series? If the days_R data in (0 to 5) then count rows of po_id in y axis, if the days_r data in (6 to 10) then add another series and then the count rows of PO_ID in y axis. I tried with that chart. I do not know the exact way of implementing that. Any help appreciated. TIA